# Running into problems using the thetaf function in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, tsibble

I am currently having some issues with the thetaf function in R (Which is from the 'Forecast' package.) The idea is that I am trying to create a forecast based on a tsibble from the previous year. The tsibble itself is daily. I have checked with the is.tsibble function if it is a tsibble and the answer is yes.

```
> is_tsibble(Daily_Tsibble2017)
[1] TRUE
```

When using the thetaf function, I get the following.

```
> thetaf(Daily_Tsibble2017,h = 365)
Error in complete.cases(x, y, wt) : 
  not all arguments have the same length
```

Since someone kindly commented on how to improve this post, I will give a short example. Since the thetaf function does need a tsibble to work, I create one first.

```
> tsibble(
+     Year = 1:10,
+     Items = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 12, 18, 20, 45, 19, 13),
+     index = Year
+ ) -> Test_Tsibble
```

If I then run the thetaf function it gives me the following error

```
> thetaf(Test_Tsibble,h=10)
Error in complete.cases(x, y, wt) : 
  not all arguments have the same length
```

Now, I do have to admit that this is my first time with the thetaf function so I would not be surprised if it is a basic mistake but I would really appreciate an answer and a solution to this issue of mine.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll want to produce a minimal, reproducible example of the issue. [Some guidance on doing so is here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  It sounds like you have missing data on some variable but not others that is causing an issue. You'll also want to specify packages (I think `thetaf` is from `forecast`?)

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice. I did edit the post. But yes, thetaf is from the Forecast package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forecast package functions, including `thetaf()`, use `ts` objects not `tsibble` objects.

If you want to use a `tsibble` object, then you can use the `fable::THETA()` function to fit the model.

If you want to use the `forecast::thetaf()` function, then convert your `tsibble` object to a `ts` object.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick answer. It seems that I did not pay enough attention to the description of the formula and just assumed that it was referring to a `tsibble` object.